# Sequlize how to use joined table's attribute name in a where clase

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have three tables

1. restaurant_items
2. restaurants
3. regions

My association is

**restaurant has many restaurant_items**

**restaurant_items belongs to restaurants**

**restaurant belongs to regions**

I want to query the restaurant items table to get items where they should comes from a specific region.

This is my code.

```
const results = await db.restaurant_items.findAll({
            where: {
                region_id: 3
            },
            include: [{
                model: db.restaurants,
                attributes: ['region_id']
            }]
        })
```

Sequlize gives me the error

> Unknown column 'restaurant_items.region_id

of-cause this is not with the restaurant_items. It is with the restaurants table. But how do I achieve this?

Comment: Please post your raw query also.

Comment: code works when I put my where clause inside include array. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add where case in your include. Try

```
const results = await db.restaurant_items.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: db.restaurants,
            where: {
              region_id: 3
            }
        }]
    })
```